# prove that ${1 \over 2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} {\lvert {re^{i\theta} \over (1 - re^{i\theta}) ^2}\rvert} d\theta = {r \over 1- r^2}$, where $0 \lt r \lt1$.

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Let $z = e^{i\theta}$, and I get $${1 \over 2\pi i} \int_{\lvert z \rvert = 1} {r \over \lvert r^2 z^2 - 2rz + 1\rvert}{dz \over z}$$
Then I get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:)** From
$$|1 - re^{i\theta}|^2=(1 - re^{i\theta})\overline{(1 - re^{i\theta})}=1+r^2-2r\cos\theta$$
we find
$${1 \over 2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} {\lvert {re^{i\theta} \over (1 - re^{i\theta}) ^2}\rvert} d\theta = {1 \over 2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} {{r \over 1+r^2-2r\cos\theta}} d\theta$$

Comment: ${{Thank you} \over {very much}}!$

Comment: cute ${}{}{}$..

Comment: Got another way to solve it. Let $z = re^{i\theta}$, then $\bar{z} = {r^2 \over z}$. The integral becomes $${1 \over {2\pi i}} \int_{\lvert z \rvert = r} {r \over {(1-z) (z - r^2)}}dz$$

Comment: so why you didn't solve it by this way?

Comment: just got it. By cauchy's integral formula, it equals $r \over (1 - z)$ evaluated at $z = r^2$.

Comment: my question.?..